# PHP: static перменная в обычной функции

Tags: php

Пытаюсь с помощью статичной переменой и такой-то матери организовать функцию для вывода текста.
Толи я как-то не так использую static, то ли что-то не так работает :(
Где я ошибся?

```
function read_stdout($filename) {

    static $seek;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    fseek($handle, $seek);
    flock($handle, LOCK_SH) ? true : exit("can not lock file $handle");
    while (($string = fgets($handle))) {
        $out[] = trim($string);
    }

    //файловый указатель
    $sk = ftell($handle);        
    $seek = $sk;
    //end - файловый указатель

    fclose($handle);
    return $out;
}
```

**UPD:**
Функция вызывается раз в минуту и читает логи.
Статичная переменная хранит позицию файлового указателя. Это нужно что бы не читать одни и теже логи несколько раз.

Comment: А зачем вообще здесь статическая переменная?

Comment: проапдейтил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я кажется сам разобрался.
К функции идёт обращение через аякс с другой страницы.
Когда все данные отправлены и скрипт с функцией закончил работу, статичная переменная (логично) уничтожается.
Если никто не скажет, что я не так использовал статичную переменную, буду прикручивать сессию для той же цели(хранить указатель).

Comment: @zenith, переменная статична в одном контексте. Если бы вы внутри страницы вызывали 2 раза всё было бы нормально. А так, она обнуляется при новом запросе